# Raspian - emails won't send in postfix

Tags: email, raspberry-pi, raspbian, sendmail, ssmtp

Context: I'm working with my raspberry pie in my local private network. I just want to be able to let cron send me emails, but instead I get this following error from sending my last email. To see this error, I used the `mailq` command

```
(delivery temporarily suspended: SASL authentication failed; cannot authenticate to server smtp.gmail.com[75.124.190.102]: no mechanism available)
                                         recipientname@domain.com
```

What could be wrong? I set up my /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd file like so:

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 my@gmail.com:myPassword
```

And here's my /etc/postfix/main.cf file:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Raspbian)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2



# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.


smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = raspberrypi
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $myhostname, raspberrypi, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all



# enable SASL authentication
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
# disallow methods that allow anonymous authentication.
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
# where to find sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
# Enable STARTTLS encryption
smtp_use_tls = yes
# where to find CA certificates
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: try removing `smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous` and adding `smtp_sasl_mechanism_filter = login`. also check if you have 2FA enabled on your gmail account, in which case, you'd have to set up application password (https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en) to use instead of your password.